# Nested foreach loops

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have an array that looks like this

```
$foreacharray = array(
    "model" => array ("samsung", "sony", "philips", "acer", "hp"),
    "qty" => array("3", "7", "5", "1", "8"),
);
```

What I'm trying to do is foreach model, draw the logo for  the amount of its qty so Samsung = 3, Sony = 7 and so on will draw 3 Sony logos and 7 Samsung logos.

I came up with something like this

```
foreach ($foreacharray["model"] as $model)
{
    foreach($foreacharray["qty"] as $qty)
    {
        echo $model;
        echo '<br>';
    }
}
```

But of course all that does is for each of the array entries, echo out the name so I end up with 5 samsungs being printed 5 sonys being printed etc.

How can I make this use the value of the qty array rather than the number of entries?

Comment: Are you in control of the array generation? If so, just generate a single array with the model as the key and the qty as the value.

Comment: Yes its easy to answer the question but I'm with @Mark Parnell

Comment: @Mark You should post that as an answer. There are already "answers" that respond directly to the question. However, sometimes the best answer is the one that puts someone onto a completely different track. Q. What's the best way to chop carrots with a chainsaw? A. Put down the chainsaw and use a knife.

Comment: I like your analogy @csj. I'll do that.

Comment: @csj: A. Buy carrots that aren’t quite so hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not make this simpler by using the function `array_combine`?

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php

Example;

```
$newArray = array_combine($foreacharray[0], $foreacharray[1]);
var_dump($newArray);
// will output
array (
     "samsung" => 3,
     "sony" => 7,
     "philips" => 5,
     "acer" => 1, 
     "hp" => 8,
)
```

Then you can easily get all values or display them like so...

```
foreach($newArray as $key => $val) {
    echo $key . ' has a quantity of ' . $val . '.';
}
```

Hope this makes it easier.

Answer (score 1):

If you are in control of the array generation in the first place, then you are better off just generating a single array with the model as the key and the qty as the value, rather than generating 2 separate arrays.

Comment: It hadn't even occurred to me to do it like this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`array_combine`](http://php.net/array_combine) to use models as keys and quantities as values, assuming models are unique:

```
$combined = array_combine($foreacharray['model'], $foreacharray['qty']);

foreach($combined as $model => $qty) {
    # …
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I never knew about array_combine, this will come in handy.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to do this:

```
for( $i = 0, $e = count( $foreacharray["model"] ); $i < $e; ++ $i ) {
    echo $foreacharray["model"][$i] . ' = ' . $foreacharray["qty"][$i] . '<br />';
}
```

Basically, a single loop references both arrays at the same index.

You could also use foreach, if you prefer, like this:

```
foreach( $foreacharray["model"] as $key => $model ) {
    echo $model . ' = ' . $foreacharray["qty"][$key] . '<br />';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate using array the array index instead, for example:

```
for (i=0; i<count($foreacharray["model"]); i++)
{
    $model = $foreacharray["model"][i];
    $qty = $foreacharray["qty"][i];
    echo "$model: $qty";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// #1 using one for keys, another for values:
foreach(array_combine($foreacharray['model'],$foreacharray['qty']) as $model => $nr){
        var_dump($model,$nr);
}
// #2 map them with null:
foreach(array_map(null,$foreacharray['model'],$foreacharray['qty']) as $data){
        var_dump($data);
}
// #3 iterators!
$iterator = new MultipleIterator();
$iterator->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($foreacharray['model']));
$iterator->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($foreacharray['qty']));
foreach($iterator as $data){
        var_dump($data);
}
```

But best would indeed be changing this at the source.

Answer (score 0):

Your `$foreacharray["qty"]` has 5 elements, because of that when You loop this by `foreach`,  it prints all `$foreacharray["model"]` elements 5 times. Your code works how, how it written.